# Error "No suitable driver" with jdbc, tomcat, apache and mod-jk

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, apache2, mod-jk

I'm installing a webapp in amazon EC2 created by a software provider.

Enviroment details:

- Operative System: ubuntu oneiric
- java: oracle-java7-jre (taken from [Eugenesan's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~eugenesan/+archive/boiler))
- tomcat: repository tomcat7
- apache: repository apache2
- mod-jd: repository libapache2-mod-jk
- mysql connector: repository libmysql-java

I follow [this tutorial](http://technonstop.com/run-phpmyadmin-alongside-tomcat-webapps) for deploy the web app with apache2+tomcat7+mod-jk.

Conf files:

- [/etc/tomcat7/server.xml](http://dpaste.com/hold/673561/)
- [/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/planeador](http://dpaste.com/hold/673562/)
- [/etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties](http://dpaste.com/hold/673563/) (here I set tomcat path and java path)

I copied the file mysql-5.1.10.jar into /myapp/WEB-INF/lib **and** /usr/share/tomcat7/lib **and** /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib (this is location for oracle-java7-jre package)

But when I go to [the site](http://planeador.innovacioncolombiaaprende.net) (the dns is fine) and clic on any link I got [this error](http://pastebin.com/Txce8sbx):

```
ERR: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql//planeador.c6qzkmwukf5s.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/planeador?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8'
```

But I checked the access to database and is fine.

Any suggest? This is my first thime installing tomcat and that stuff, please If I'm missing some obvius part tell me.

Thanks

Comment: What's "SO: ubuntu oneiric" ?

Comment: the connection url for database? yes, the subdomain for apache? yes

Comment: Shouldn't it be `jdbc:mysql://planeador.`? I mean the colon after mysql.

Comment: What gurung said.  Shouldn't you have a colon between "mysql" and "//planeador"?

Comment: Please, write it like an answer. you are right, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ERR: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql//planeador.c6qzkmwukf5s.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/planeador?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8'

You are missing a colon (`:`) between `mysql` and `//` in your connection url.

[19.3.4.1. Driver/Datasource Class Names, URL Syntax and Configuration Properties for Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)